# Where should I put IBOutlets and IBActions?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

Here's some example code to explain myself:

**MyViewController.h**

```
@interface MyViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
  - (IBAction)button1Touch;
@end
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
- (IBAction)button2Touch;
@end

@implementation MyViewController {
  IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
}

- (IBAction)button1Touch {
}

- (IBAction)button2Touch {
}

- (IBAction)button3Touch {
}

@end
```

When I learned how to use XCode, all tutorials used `button1`/`button1Touch` approach. Recently I've encountered `button2`/`button2Touch` approach in one project. So I tried `button3`/`button3Touch` variation and it works fine as well.

For me `button1`/`button1Touch` is (generally) a bad approach, because it's internal property and method and shouldn't be used by someone who'll use `MyViewController` or extend it. Of course if it's used outside of MyViewController, then it's fine to declare it here, but usually I'm trying to hide everything I don't need to show.

So `button2`/`button2Touch` and `button3`/`button3Touch` are better approaches, but I don't really see difference between them. And if I don't see the difference, then I would use `button3`/`button3Touch` approach, because it doesn't need anonymous extension and simpler overall.

So that's my reasoning. But is it correct one or there are other reasons why I would use #1/#2 approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd approach allows you to use `@property` (which is not possible in the 3rd approach as you already found out I guess, since the compiler complains).

It is more common (and cleaner, in my opinion) to declare all your private properties and methods in the class extension (what you refer to as "anonymous extension").

I'm also curious if there are more serious caveats by using your 3rd approach - if someone knows please share.